# Windows 8 xaml - Best practices: From design mockup to App?

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-8, adobe-illustrator

What are the best practices for Windows 8 xaml apps to bring in the Visual Design assets?

We started designing our app in Adobe Illustrator so all graphics would be vector based and scalable. Now we have the screen designs, but can't find a way to bring them into the actual app (xaml/c#) . I thought there is a way to import SVG to Visual Studio or Blend, but we can't find it. For Windows Phone there even was an Illustrator import feature.

Answer (score 1):

The Import from Illustrator feature is missing from the current version of Blend, unfortunately. You can however use Expression Blend 4 to import the relevant XAML form Illustrator and then copy/paste into Blend 5.

Cheers
Laurent